# Error CS0019 in Unity C# for using multi variable switch statements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I keep getting "error CS0019: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'double'". Both of the variables being used are doubles and I have tried a few different ways to make this work. My code is here:
`

```
    switch((xPos, yPos))
    {
        case ((-7.445 < xPos < -6.795) && (4.15 > yPos > 3.45)):
            xPos = -7.12;
            yPos = 3.805;
            break;
        case ((-7.445 < xPos < -6.795) && (3.35 > yPos > 2.65)):
            xPos = -7.12;
            yPos = 3.005;
            break;
        case ((-7.445 < xPos < -6.795) && (2.55 > yPos > 1.85)):
            xPos = -7.12;
            yPos = 2.205;
            break;
        case ((-7.445 < xPos < -6.795) && (1.75 > yPos > 1.05)):
            xPos = -7.12;
            yPos = 1.405;
            break;
        case ((-7.445 < xPos < -6.795) && (0.95 > yPos > 0.25)):
            xPos = -7.12;
            yPos = 0.605;
            break;
        case ((-7.445 < xPos < -6.795) && (0.15 > yPos > -0.55)):
            xPos = -7.12;
            yPos = -0.195;
            break;
        case ((-7.445 < xPos < -6.795) && (-0.65 > yPos > -1.35)):
            xPos = -7.12;
            yPos = -0.995;
            break;
        case ((-7.445 < xPos < -6.795) && (-1.45 > yPos > -2.15)):
            xPos = -7.12;
            yPos = -1.795;
            break;
        case ((-7.445 < xPos < -6.795) && (-2.25 > yPos > -2.95)):
            xPos = -7.12;
            yPos = -2.595;
            break;
        case ((-7.445 < xPos < -6.795) && (-3.05 > yPos > -3.75)):
            xPos = -7.12;
            yPos = -3.395;
            break;
        case ((-7.445 < xPos < -6.795) && (-3.85 > yPos > -4.55)):
            xPos = -7.12;
            yPos = -4.195;
            break;`
```

I have tried using the following examples:
`case ((-7.445 < xPos < -6.795), (-3.85 > yPos > -4.55)): case 1 when ((-7.445 < xPos < -6.795), (-3.85 > yPos > -4.55)): case 1 when (-7.445 < xPos < -6.795), (-3.85 > yPos > -4.55): case 1 when -7.445 < xPos < -6.795, -3.85 > yPos > -4.55:`
and nothing has worked so far. I am using this to determine where an object is placed on a grid, so I'd like to check the x-position and y-position at the same time instead of using nested switch statements for obvious reasons.

Comment: (-7.445 < xPos < -6.795) will not work, it has to be -7.445 < xpos && xpos < -6.795

Comment: why though? The check for `xPos` and assigned value is the same for all cases ... why not check this separately? I would claim that the pattern way makes this actually harder to read and maintain

Comment: This is just a small section of the switch statement. The full grid being checked is 11x21 spaces, so the xPos value does change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using [constant or relational patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#relational-patterns), you don't need to specify variable names, and use `and`/`or` to combine conditions.

e.g.

```
case (> -7.445 and < -6.795, < 4.15 and > 3.45):
```